# Using 'echo' with a patch command fails

Tags: linux, echo, patch

I am trying to embed a patch in a script. When I do:

```
x=$(diff x y)
echo $x | patch x
```

it works. But when I embed the diff in an echo in a script it doesn't work. Here is the precise code I'm working with:

```
echo '
75c75
<           print_stacktrace();
---
> //            print_stacktrace();
93c93,134
< int main(int argc, char **argv) {
---
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
>     if (argc > 1 ) {
>         if ( strcmp(argv[1], "--list") == 0 ) {
>             CxxTest::TestRunner::listTests();
> 
>         } else {
>             struct sigaction act;
>             memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));
>             act.sa_handler = sig_handler;
>             sigaction(SIGHUP, &act, 0);
>             sigaction(SIGQUIT, &act, 0);
>             sigaction(SIGILL, &act, 0);
>             sigaction(SIGABRT, &act, 0);
>             sigaction(SIGFPE, &act, 0);
>             sigaction(SIGKILL, &act, 0);
>             sigaction(SIGSEGV, &act, 0);
>             sigaction(SIGPIPE, &act, 0);
>             sigaction(SIGALRM, &act, 0);
>             sigaction(SIGTERM, &act, 0);
>             signal(SIGWINCH, SIG_IGN);
> 
>         //--- Skip program name
>             argv++;
> 
>         //--- Note if we can fork() tests
>             if ( *argv != 0  &&  strcmp(*argv, "--fork") == 0 ) {
>                 fork_tests = true;
>                 argv++;
>             }
> 
>             ArthurFixture fixture(*argv++);
> 
>         //--- Collect modules to test. If none, test all.
>             std::set<const char*> args;
>             while ( *argv != 0 ) {
>                 args.insert(*argv);
>                 argv++;
>             }
> 
>         //--- Run tests.
>             return CxxTest::ErrorPrinter().run(args);
>         }
95,124c136
<   if (argc > 1) {
<       if ( strcmp(argv[1], "list") == 0 ) {
<           CxxTest::TestRunner::listTests();
< 
<       } else {
<           struct sigaction act;
<           memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));
<           act.sa_handler = sig_handler;
<           sigaction(SIGHUP, &act, 0);
<           sigaction(SIGQUIT, &act, 0);
<           sigaction(SIGILL, &act, 0);
<           sigaction(SIGABRT, &act, 0);
<           sigaction(SIGFPE, &act, 0);
<           sigaction(SIGKILL, &act, 0);
<           sigaction(SIGSEGV, &act, 0);
<           sigaction(SIGPIPE, &act, 0);
<           sigaction(SIGALRM, &act, 0);
<           sigaction(SIGTERM, &act, 0);
<           signal(SIGWINCH, SIG_IGN);
< 
<           argv++, argc--;
<           ArthurFixture fixture(*argv);
<           std::set<const char*> args;
< 
<           for ( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ ) {
<               args.insert(argv[i]);
<           }
<           return CxxTest::ErrorPrinter().run(args);
<       }
<   } else {
---
>     } else {
' | patch acceptanceTests/test-root.cpp.normal
```

Each hunk fails. The reason I am not putting the diff's in separate files is the script may be anywhere in the file system. I tried to 'echo' the diff to a file, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: why are you doing this... you are asking for trouble. we are not going to read your string char by char to identify what confuses shell's parser.

Comment: Forget it. Comments without even a link to said duplicate is unhelpful.